# Simplest LINQ many-to-many solution

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a many-to-many relationship between `Students` and `Classes`, and I've created a linking table called `Students_Classes`, what's the simplest way to get a list of classes from a StudentID?

Right now I'm doing the following (which I know is not elegant):

```
List<Class> classes = new List<Class>();
List<Students_Classes> students_classes = db.Students_Classes.Where(s => s.StudentID == id).ToList();

foreach (var item in students_classes)
{
    classes.Add(item.Class);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is actually ok, however, you could do it in one query i.e.

```
var classes = (from s in db.Students_Classes
               where s.StudentID == id
               select s.Class).ToList();
```

or since you appear to prefer Lambda to LINQ

```
var classes = db.Student_Classes.Where(s => s.StudentID == id)
                                .Select(s => s.Class)
                                .ToList();
```